# How do I plot this using seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

rankings_by_age = star_wars.groupby("Age").agg(np.mean).iloc[:,8:]

age_first = rankings_by_age.iloc[0, :].values
age_second = rankings_by_age.iloc[1, :].values
age_third = rankings_by_age.iloc[2, :].values
age_fourth = rankings_by_age.iloc[3, :].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))

ind = np.arange(6)
width = 0.2

rects_1 = ax.bar(ind, age_first, width, color=(114/255,158/255,206/255), 
alpha=.8)
rects_2 = ax.bar(ind+width, age_second, width, color=
(255/255,158/255,74/255), alpha=.8)
rects_3 = ax.bar(ind+2*width, age_third, width, color=
(103/255,191/255,92/255), alpha=.8)
rects_4 = ax.bar(ind+3*width, age_fourth, width, color=
(237/255,102/255,93/255), alpha=.8)

ax.set_title("Star Wars Film Rankings by Age")
ax.set_ylabel("Ranking")
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(titles, rotation=45)

ax.tick_params(top='off', right='off', left='off', bottom='off')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax.legend((rects_1[0], rects_2[0], rects_3[0], rects_4[0]), ('18-29', '30-
44', '45-60', '> 60'), title="Age")

plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to replicate this plot using seaborn, but I am not sure how to go about plotting multiple bars for each category. I understand how to do it using one age group at a time, but getting more than one bar per age group seems tricky. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll get better responses if you (1) show your best working Seaborn code, and (2) show your best failed attempt at doing multiple bars.  That reduces the corrections to a line or two.

Comment: The question is unclear. The code from the question (apart from not being reproducible, see [mcve]) already gives the desired result. So what exactly does "using seaborn" mean here?

Comment: Also these rankings are terrible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [seaborn bar plot documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), you can use the `hue` argument to determine which column of the dataframe the bars should be grouped by.

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for being unclear. I understand the `hue` argument, but I am wondering if I can plot multiple columns per day. For example, if I wanted to plot `total_bill` and `total_tip` per day (given that they share the same units, so the same y-axis can be used). So, with the `hue` argument set to `sex`, the total number of bars would be 4 per day in your above example.

Comment: If you want to use the `sns.barplot` function, you need to reorganize the data such that there is a column with the respective features in. This is the drawback of seaborn; it only works with pretty standarized data formats.